Laravel, Laravel Blade, Generation Error Exception Undefined Variable $helper when I click the home page navigations second link
I refactored my code, even so, I'm still generated the same Error Exception. I will show the old code and the refactored code. I'll also provided the error message generated by Laravel. in addition to the spaghetti code I received when troubleshooting the error with dd().
I have my own custom made helper functions that I'm using. It's a class and is injected into the home page Controller as a dependency. My helper function is then passed to Laravel Blade as a variable named helper.
The goal is to have my navigation links change to a different color if it is the currently selected and active link to that page.
When I apply the $helper variable to the first link, I get my desired result. However, the $helper variable generates the Undefined Variable $helper Error Exception on all the other links.
I used dd() to troubleshoot the error. I received a output of spaghetti code as a result.
Utilities/Helper class example - my custom helper function

/*
* Original
*/

<?php

namespace App\Utilities;

class Helper
{
  public static function activePage(string $pageUrl): string
  {
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    return $requestUri === $pageUrl ? "color=var(--sky)" : "color=var(--mud)";   
  }
}

/*
* Refactored
*/

<?php

namespace App\Utilities;

class Helper
{
  public static function activePage(string $pageUrl): string
  {    
    return Request::is($pageUri) ? "style=color:var(--sky)" : "style=color:var(--mud)";   
  }
}


Controller/Home Action example

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Utilities\Helper;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class Home extends BaseController
{

  public function __construct(
   private Helper $helper,  
  ){}

  public function index(): View
  {
    return view('home', [
      'helper' => $this->helper::class,
    ]);
  }
}


Laravel Blade Template home page example

<!-- Original -->

<li class="nav-links">        
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}"         style="{{ $helper::activePage('/') }}">Home</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/services') }}" style="{{ $helper::activePage('/services') }}">Services</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/clients') }}"  style="{{ $helper::activePage('/clients') }}">Clients</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/about') }}"    style="{{ $helper::activePage('/about') }}">About</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/blog') }}"     style="{{ $helper::activePage('/blog') }}">Blog</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}"  style="{{ $helper::activePage('/contact') }}" class="contact-link">Contact</a>
</li>

<!-- Refactored -->

<li class="nav-links">        
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}"         {{ $helper::activePage('/') }}>Home</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/services') }}" {{ $helper::activePage('/services') }}>Services</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/clients') }}"  {{ $helper::activePage('/clients') }}>Clients</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/about') }}"    {{ $helper::activePage('/about') }}>About</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/blog') }}"     {{ $helper::activePage('/blog') }}>Blog</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}"  {{ $helper::activePage('/contact') }} class="contact-link">Contact</a>
</li>

<!-- Also tried: no error occurred, but was not able to get the color to change to var(--sky) on the second link -->

<li class="nav-links">        
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}" {{ Request::is('/') ? "style=color:var(--sky)" : "style=color:var(--mud)" }}>Home</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/services') }}" {{ Request::is('/services') ? "style=color:var(--sky)" : "style=color:var(--mud)" }}>Services</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/clients') }}">Clients</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/about') }}">About</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/blog') }}">Blog</a>
  <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}" class="contact-link">Contact</a>
</li>


Image of Error Exception
Laravel Error Message
Laravel Error Code
Generated unformatted spaghetti code when using dd()

Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { doc.documentElement.classList.add('sf-js-enabled'); var rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▼'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▶'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e, n) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else { n = /\bsf-dump-ellipsis\b/.test(e.target.className) ? e.target.parentNode : e.target; if ((n = n.nextElementSibling) && 'A' == n.tagName) { if (!/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(n.className)) { n = n.nextElementSibling || n; } f(n, e, true); } } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').slice(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += elt.className == 'sf-dump-compact' ? '▶' : '▼'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.slice(1); elt.className += ' sf-dump-hover'; elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' ▶'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '▶'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '…'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(), currentRect, searchRect; if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); if ('scrollIntoView' in currentNode) { currentNode.scrollIntoView(true); currentRect = currentNode.getBoundingClientRect(); searchRect = search.getBoundingClientRect(); if (currentRect.top < (searchRect.top + searchRect.height)) { window.scrollBy(0, -(searchRect.top + searchRect.height + 5)); } } } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' 
 0 of 0<\/span>


After reading the code, is there anything you think would cause an error to occur?

This question is similar to: How to Get the Current URL Inside @if Statement (Blade) in Laravel 4?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In your helper class "Helper", add dd($requestUri); before return in your static method "activePage" to debug what is going on with your custom helper class.

In your public function index(), its return not reutrn, 2nd in 'helper' => $this->helper::class,, remove ::class

@Mr.Daniels Down votes mean a question is not well researched enough, as well as what else the tooltip for the down arrow says.  They are not intended to be negative, but to signal the question could use improvement.  This is well defined in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

@Mr.Daniels No bashing has occurred.  Down votes are not bashing; they're a quality indicator.  I did not criticize your post or you, I attempted to help you understand how the platform works.  If you want me to criticize your post, it is not well researched enough because the ::class magic static property returns a string, not a class instance.  People have tried to help you; they've already pointed out the ::class misunderstanding, and they've suggested the debug.  Someone even provided an answer, as wrong as it may be.  No one has insulted you, and no one has been mean.

@Mr.Daniels Secondly, where have you defined your class in the service container?
I see the class defined, but not registered. Lastly, have you considered that you are not returning a view from your controller, but a response?  While I have used laravel for quite some time, I never specify the return as being a view, but a response object, so I don't have enough experience in that regard to say whether or not your return constraint will modify the behavior or not.

@Daedalus You are correct regarding ::class. According to php documentation, ::class returns the fully qualified namespace as a string. You are correct regarding my Class not being registered in Laravel’s service container. Laravel’s documentation provides several way to render a view. A view can be passed via the router without the need of the controller. Laravel’s documentation also states one of their most basic controller returns a view. Meaning Laravel is not very opinionated in that regard. You can return a Response or a View, I haven’t learned the effects of that yet.

@Daedalus After I make these changes you suggested and the bug is no more… I’ll post the solution in this thread.

The Solution to Laravel Undefined Variable Error Exception. To keep it very simple. Each controller renders a view. So if you're working on the home page nav links and each controller renders a view for each of those links. You'll receive an Error Exception if you try to echo a variable on the other links and missing the fact that you didn't passed the variable through your other controllers first. I'll provide code examples below.
Helper Function / Dependency

class helper
{
  public static function pleaseHelp(string $param): string
  {
    return // your code
  }
}


Controllers

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Utilities\Helper;

// The variable 'set' works on the rendered home page and the home nav link.
// It will not work on the other nav links without causing the Error Exception.
 
class Home
{
  public function __construct(
    private Helper $pleaseHelp,
  ){}
  
  public function index(): View
  {
    return view('home', [
      'set' => $this->pleaseHelp,
    ]);
  }
}

// In order to get your nav links working on the other pages, you'll need
// to inject your Helper Dependency into your other controller class.
  
class About
{
  // Helper Dependency here...

  return view('about', [
    'set' => $this->pleaseHelp,
  ]);
}

class Contact
{
  // Helper Dependency here too...

  return view('contact', [
    'set' => $this->pleaseHelp,
  ]);
}


Laravel Blade / html

// Link about & contact can now read the variable $set and load the page without error
<nav>
  <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="{{ $set::pleaseHelp('/') }}">Home</a>
  <a href="{{ url('about') }}" class="{{ $set::pleaseHelp('about') }}">About</a>
  <a href="{{ url('contact') }}" class="{{ $set::pleaseHelp('contact') }}">Contact</a>
</nav>



What about registering your helper in the service container?

@Daedalus What I found interesting was after running a few tests, I checked to see if the service container was needed. Turns out, the service container is not required in this instance. I'm able to use my Helper Dependency without any issues. My theory is, knowing that the App directory is already bootstrapped, your custom classes my be registered indirectly. just don't quote me on that.

You never use $_SERVER in Laravel.
Read the entire documentation page. It's part of Laravel's standard functionality.
<a href="{{ url('/') }}" style="@if(request()->is('/'))
 ... 
@else 
 ...
@endif">Home</a>

It is recommended that you start by using Breeze to learn the Laravel.
https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/2.x/stubs/default/resources/views/components/nav-link.blade.php
https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/2.x/stubs/default/resources/views/layouts/navigation.blade.php
<x-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
    {{ __('Dashboard') }}
</x-nav-link>

The current common way to use Laravel is to utilize the Blade component.

I'm using custom helper functions for my project. My helpers will be used to interact with Laravel Blades front end. I'm sticking with Vite and Laravel Blade. I'm not using components. You need to find a better way of help people understand what you are talking about... your examples didn't help out at all.
